# SQL Server bulk insert doesn't recognize double quotes as fieldquote

Tags: sql-server, unix, bulkinsert, double-quotes, line-endings

I'm trying to bulk insert a file in **SQL Server 2017 14.0.1000.169**. I would like to take the file exactly as it arrives, save it to the desired location and then run the bulk insert query **without having to modify the file** at all. I'm having difficulties getting the script to recognize and ignore the double quotes in the text file unless I manually change the line endings from Unix to Windows. I have read quite a few topics here and outside of SO discussing subjects close to this one, alas, none of which gave me the answer to my question:

***How do I bulk insert my file with Unix line endings and not end up with double quotes?***

My **file** looks like this:

```
"Report Name","Daily Extract (ID: 111111)"
"Date/Time Generated(UTC)","01-Mar-2020 15:08:51"
"Workspace Name","Company (ID: 22222)"
"Account Name","Client Account"
"Date Range","01-Jan-2019 - 29-Feb-2020"

"Dimension 1","Dimension 2","Dimension 3","Dimension 4","Dimension 5","Dimension 6","Dimension 7","Dimension 8","Dimension 9","Dimension 10","Dimension 11","Dimension 12","Dimension 13","Dimension 14","Dimension 15","Dimension 16","Dimension 17","Metric 1","Metric 2","Metric 3","Metric 4","Metric 5","Metric 6","Metric 7","Metric 8","Metric 9","Metric 10","Metric 11","Metric 12"
"string","string","date as string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","bigint","bigint","decimal","decimal","decimal","bigint","decimal","decimal","bigint","decimal","bigint","bigint"
```

The **query** I'm using as follows:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table](
    [Dimension 1] [varchar] (255) NULL,
    [Dimension 2] [varchar] (255) NULL,
    [Dimension 3] [varchar] (255) NULL,
    [Dimension 4] [varchar]  (255) NULL,
    [Dimension 5] [varchar] (255),
    [Dimension 6] [varchar] (255) NULL,
    [Dimension 7] [varchar] (255) NULL,
    [Dimension 8] [varchar] (255) NULL,
    [Dimension 9] [varchar] (1000) NULL,
    [Dimension 10] [varchar] (255) NULL,
    [Dimension 11] [varchar] (255) NULL,
    [Dimension 12] [varchar] (255) NULL,
    [Dimension 13] [varchar] (1000) NULL,
    [Dimension 14] [varchar] (1000) NULL,
    [Dimension 15] [varchar] (1000) NULL,
    [Dimension 16] [varchar] (1000) NULL,
    [Dimension 17] [varchar] (1000) NULL,
    [Metric 1] [varchar] (50) NULL,
    [Metric 2] [varchar] (50) NULL,
    [Metric 3] [varchar] (50) NULL,
    [Metric 4] [varchar] (50) NULL,
    [Metric 5] [varchar] (50) NULL,
    [Metric 6] [varchar] (50) NULL,
    [Metric 7] [varchar] (50) NULL,
    [Metric 8] [varchar] (50) NULL,
    [Metric 9] [varchar] (50) NULL,
    [Metric 10] [varchar] (255) NULL,
    [Metric 11] [varchar] (50) NULL,
    [Metric 12] [varchar] (50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

BULK
INSERT Table
FROM 'C:\Users\username\Folder\File.csv'
WITH
(
--FORMAT = 'CSV',
DATAFILETYPE = 'char',
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
--ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',
FIRSTROW = 7,
--FIELDQUOTE = '"'
FIELDQUOTE = '0x22'
)
;
```

As you can see above, I'm importing everything as a varchar. Originally I only used this for one metric (due to data quality issues on supply end), as I fully intend to correct every blemish after the file has already been loaded. Having run into difficulties however I have set all metrics to varchar, so at least the file would load and I could see what it looks like and dig further.

So far I **have tried** the following:

- open the file in Sublime, remove first 7 rows, change line ending to Windows and save - this works with the lines I have commented out, i.e. FORMAT instead of DATAFILETYPE, \n instead of 0x0a and with the FIELDQUOTE of "
- leave the file untouched and run the above script with double-quote instead of 0x22 - this also works, but the end result is that every value is in double quotes
- leave the file untouched and run the above script as it is (i.e. using 0x22 for the FIELDQUOTE) - again, works, but with double quotes everywhere

Every other thing I have tried so far resulted in various errors, which all lead back to the same two things: either I can't use FORMAT = 'CSV' (if I leave the Unix line endings in), or the moment I try loading metrics as float, it errors out because of the double-quotes.

I do have a workaround for the time being (I can remove the double quotes and convert the fields after the thing has loaded), I do wonder however whether I can integrate that step into the bulk insert (like I did when I loaded the file with Windows endings).

N.B. I am aware that FIELDQUOTE hasn't been around for too long, it should, however, apply to my build, as per Microsoft:

> "FIELDQUOTE = 'field_quote' Applies to: SQL Server 2017 (14.x) CTP
>   1.1. Specifies a character that will be used as the quote character in the CSV file. If not specified, the quote character (") will be used
>   as the quote character as defined in the RFC 4180 standard."

Did I forget to disclose anything? If not, any ideas what I might have overlooked?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You commented out `FORMAT = 'CSV'` in your example though.

Comment: under the example you can read why: the bit that's commented out was ran on the file with Windows line endings, the ones in use were tried with Unix line endings. The one exception is the FIELDQUOTE, of which I have tried both versions (" and 0x22) with the Unix line endings. Hope that makes sense?

Comment: Also, I have tried FORMAT with the Unix endings, and it threw an error. I read it in another thread on SO (one I can't now find for the life of me) that the OP should be using DATAFILETYPE instead, which I tried and it worked, hence the substitution. I might be missing something else though, I don't know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. The biggest problem here is your file. Firstly, the file does not [RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180), due to rows at the top. This makes for a headache.

Next is the **important** caveat on `FIRSTROW`:

> When skipping rows, the SQL Server Database Engine looks only at the **field terminators**, and does not validate the data in the fields of skipped rows.

Notice this says **field terminators** *not* row terminators. This is the second problem. For your data, you have this at the start:

```
"Report Name","Daily Extract (ID: 111111)"
"Date/Time Generated(UTC)","01-Mar-2020 15:08:51"
"Workspace Name","Company (ID: 22222)"
"Account Name","Client Account"
"Date Range","01-Jan-2019 - 29-Feb-2020"
<-- Blank Line -->
```

This is 6 field terminators, and 6 row terminators.

Next, you have *more* columns in the CSV file than in the table `Table`. `Table` doesn't have a column `Dimension 17`.

After adding this missing column, I managed to get this working for the results I believe you are after with the below:

```
BULK INSERT [Table]
FROM '/tmp/YourFile2.txt'
WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
      ROWTERMINATOR = '\n',
      FIRSTROW = 2,
      FORMAT = 'CSV',
      FIELDQUOTE = '"');
```

This inserted 1 row into the table.

Comment: Grand, quite a bit to which to respond here :) So, Dim 17 is a mt, I've added that into the original post to avoid confusion. The original query actually does have the right amount of columns. (Please bear with me, due to my contract, NDA etc. I have to desensitize everything to the bone before posting it anywhere, and I simply missed a column from the code here.)

Comment: With regards to the top few rows: it works for me fine when I skip the first 6 rows, I have just tried it. Same as your code above, except FIRSTROW is 7. This only works though if the line endings are that of Windows (i.e. the \n that you are using) which is NOT the case in the original file. If you remember, my goal is to not have to manually process the file at all prior to loading it, in other words: 1. keep the nonsense in the first 6 row and simply skip it (check), 2. keep the Unix line endings AND do away with the double quotes (either/or check, together nope).

Comment: *"This only works though if the line endings are that of Windows"* The test file I was working with was using `LF` line endings only. You can see this as I use `ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'`, but also, I was actually testing that on a Unix environment. I intentionally ensured I was working with a `LF` file.

Comment: Hmm.. that's strange, \n does not work for me at all with the Unix file. Just to confirm, the environment remains Windows for the whole time, it's only the file that changes. Strangely enough, when I save the file with Windows line endings (LF CR), \n works with no problems without the need for \r. Also, when I say it only works for Windows... literally, when I save the file with Unix line endings, \n does NOT work. I have to change it to 0x0a. FORMAT does not work either in that case. Maybe I could upload two files somewhere and you can test with those, as I suspect your file is different?

Comment: I have found the article(https://github.com/Microsoft/sql-server-samples/issues/408) on the back of which I have replaced FORMAT with DATAFILETYPE. I have also cleaned up my attempts a bit and found this: the Windows version of the file runs fine with the latter (regardless of RFC4180 non-compliance), BUT then FIELDQUOTE was ignored. To recap, I will either have to remove the dirty lines pre load or the double-quotes post-load. I do wonder if I can do both whilst loading... Thank you for spending time looking into it @Larnu!